# Android Eclipse If textview = text then

Tags: android, eclipse, text, get, textview

I need help for a simple code about which I can not find anything.

So if Textview1 = Text then I know it only on VB.net but i need it for android.

I hope any can help me.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - are you trying to get the text from a textview?

Comment: @Jade McGough yes you know the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following:

```
if (textView1.getText().toString().equals(Text)) //if Text isnt variable add doube quotes "text"
{
   //do something
}
```

hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: glad I was able to help you

Answer (score 0):

you must first define Your `textView`

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uniqueID); // uniqueID is a ID that yo declare in `xml` file to TextView
```

then you can get the value of that with:

```
String s = text.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current value of a TextView, you need the id value of the TextView. For example, say that the id for a TextView is "tvName".

In the activity:

```
TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
```

You find the view and set it to a TextView object. Then, you can access the current text for it with:

```
tvName.getText().toString()
```